# Problem with From field in contact form and mail() function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email-headers

I've got a contact form with 3 fields and a textarea...
I use jQuery to validate it and then php to send emails.

This contact form works fine but, when I receive an email, From field isn't correct. I'd like to want that From field shows text typed in the Name field of the contact form. Now I get a From field like this: `<nameOfMyServerAdmin@serverUrl.com>`

For example, if an user types "Matthew" in the name field, I'd like to want that this word "Matthew" appears in the From field.

This is my code (XHTML, jQuery, PHP):

```
<div id="contact">
    <h3 id="formHeader">Send Us a Message!</h3>
    <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
        <div id="risposta"></div> <!-- End Risposta Div -->
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" id="formName" value="" /><br />
        <span>E-mail:</span>
        <input type="text" id="formEmail" value="" /><br />
        <span>Subject:</span>
        <input type="text" id="formSubject" value="" /><br />
        <span>Message:</span>
        <textarea id="formMessage" rows="9" cols="20"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" id="formSend" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formSend").click(function(){

            var valid = '';
            var nome = $("#formName").val();
            var mail = $("#formEmail").val();
            var oggetto = $("#formSubject").val();
            var messaggio = $("#formMessage").val();

            if (nome.length<1) {
                valid += '<span>Name field empty.</span><br />';
            }
            if (!mail.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
                valid += '<span>Email not valid or empty field.</span><br />';
            }
            if (oggetto.length<1) {
                valid += '<span>Subject field empty.</span><br />';
            }

            if (valid!='') {
                $("#risposta").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#risposta").html("<span><b>Error:</b></span><br />"+valid);
                $("#risposta").css("background-color","#ffc0c0");
            }
            else {
                var datastr ='nome=' + nome + '&mail=' + mail + '&oggetto=' + oggetto + '&messaggio=' + encodeURIComponent(messaggio);
                $("#risposta").css("display", "block");
                $("#risposta").css("background-color","#FFFFA0");
                $("#risposta").html("<span>Sending message...</span>");
                $("#risposta").fadeIn("slow");
                setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",2000);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    function send(datastr){
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactForm.php",
            data: datastr,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
            $("#risposta").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#risposta").html('<span>Message successfully sent.</span>');
            $("#risposta").css("background-color","#e1ffc0");
            setTimeout('$("#risposta").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

<?php
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
$text = $_POST['messaggio'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$to = "support@matthewlabs.com";

$message = $text."<br /><br />IP: ".$ip."<br />";
$headers = "From: $nome \n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $mail \n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \n";

mail($to, $oggetto, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an email address in the "From:" header. Try this:

```
$headers = "From: $nome <$mail>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $mail\r\n";
```

Comment: If you want the from field to be displayed as John Doe <john.doe@example.com>:

    $headers = "From: $nome <$mail>\r\n";

Comment: I edited your post to reflect what he was trying to do, although you were technically correct.

Comment: @Kshitij Parajuli - +1, @Matthew just check the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)!

Comment: @All thanks a lot! I'm new to PHP and I didn't know about documentation... Thanks ;)